# Does MotherBoard limit RAM?

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, chipset

http://www.findlaptopdriver.com/hewlett-packard-09e0h-mainboard-specifications/

^^ That page lists the specs of my motherboard. It says that it can support

```
4 x 240-pin DDR2 DIMM slots Supports 
DDR2 533/400 non-ECC, un-buffered memory 
(Max 4GB)
```

But I Thought it was the cpu/ram slots that dictate how much ram could be installed? I'm wondering because I wanted to install 4 gb of ram, but I dont want to buy more and then figure out its not compatible.

I plan to get the PAE extension tool so I can install more than 4gb that can be used by my OS...which is Windows 8.1. So does a motherboard limit the RAM?

Quick specs of my comp

```
Cpu: Pentium 4 540(3.20 GHZ) Single Core HT
Instruction Set: 32bit
NorthBridge: Intel 915GV
SouthBridge: ICH6
Ram Slots: 4
```

Comment: This question doesn't actually ask a question. Anyway, it sounds like you have a 32bit system. The memory is limited because a 32bit system cannot access memory above ~4gb. This is why 64bit systems have become fairly standard now.

Comment: @krowe Did you miss the part about him using PAE? 32-bit systems can access *physical* memory above 4GB with PAE.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz According to this wiki page, even with PAE, Win8 is only going to allow 4GB anyway: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension

Answer (score 2):

Your CPU cannot talk directly to DIMM's. The motherboard is in between the two. In particular, the motherboard is responsible for figuring out which DIMM to talk to, when the CPU asks for a certain address. If the CPU gives an address past 4 GB, and the motherboard doesn't understand that address, it can't find the right DIMM.

(More modern CPU's work somewhat differently and need less help from the motherboard)

Comment: so when the specs list 'max(4gb)' does that mean the motherboard—even if it has more than 4gb—cannot process addresses past 4gb?

Comment: @AlienC: That is not 100% certain in general - it may be able to give your videocard an address past 4 GB (it too may require an address). But your laptop has integrated GFX so that's probably not relevant to you.

Comment: ok. for now I'm only going to use 4gb and get PAE to use all of it. If I ever want/need more I'll just wing it @MSalters

Comment: oh i got the answer to my question @MSalters. http://ark.intel.com/products/27734/Intel-915GV-Graphics-and-Memory-Controller   that page lists that the max amount of memory is 8gb and thats my chipset so i'll just go ahead and try

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, the max RAM listed by the vendor is simply the highest amount of RAM they've validated it with.  We're talking about DDR2 here.  When DDR2 was popular, 1GB sticks were the biggest you cold find.  They eventually made 4GB sticks but those probably weren't available when the specs for that motherboard were written.  It's possible it might work with more, but there's no way to know for sure.

I have a 2011 17" MacBook Pro.  According to Apple's specs, that computer can only take 8GB of RAM, but I have 16GB in it and it works fine.

Answer (score -2):

Did some research unless you gonna buy a sever board using older ram like DDR3 your most likey limited to 16gb which sucks cause i got 24 total. New boards using DDR4 seem to max at 64...
Next upgrade I plan on using a server board those seem to want more ram, and i found one with 2 processors. A little overkill but I use my computer to run video on like 4 monitors to entertain my family, plus one monitor to do high graphics gaming so it adds up.